# Why does javascript reads var as a string if i add '+' to it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I have field names in my firestore document as

videolink1-"some video link"

videolink2-"some video link"

videolink3-"some video link"

I am using a for loop to get all videolinks present in the document.

```
                if (doc.exists) {
                  
                   for (var i = 1; i == videocount; i++) { //videocount is 3

                    var data = doc.data();
                    var videolink = data.videolink+i;

  //creating new paragraph
                    var p = '<p class ="trackvideostyle">'+"Your Video Link : "+String(videolink)+'</p>\';

                    document.getElementById("btn").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', p);

                    }
```

But this for loop is creating var values which are being read as string and firestore is returning me NaN as I dont have these fields :

```
data.videolink+1

data.videolink+2   //Firestore is returning null as i dont have these document fields

data.videolink+3
```

How can I write for loop so that var values are created like this and firestore reads it as:

```
videolink1

videolink2

videolink3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try something like this,

```
var videolink = data[`videolink${i}`];
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using

#### 1. template strings

```js
..
var videolink = `${data.videolink}${i}`
..
```

#### 2. concat()

```js
.. 
var videolink = data.videolink.concat(i.toString());
..
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using "data.videolink+i" and javascript does not evaluate the value after the "." instead it is treated as the object's property. you need to use [] for evaluation.  try this I hope this will work

```
        if (doc.exists) {
                        
            for (var i = 1; i == videocount; i++) {

            var data = doc.data();
            var videolink = data[videolink+i];

        //creating new paragraph
            var p = '<p class ="trackvideostyle">'+"Your Video Link : 
        "+String(videolink)+'</p>\';

            document.getElementById("btn").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', 
         p);

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why it doesn't work**

The dot operator (property accessor) has [higher precendense](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so it is evaluated first, so you get the value of the property and then you concatenate the value of your `i` variable.

**What should you do**

You can use another property accessor - square brackets, just like in arrays:

```
data['videolink']
```

You can build your property name inside of the square brackets:

```
data['videolink' + i]
```

or using template literals:

```
data[`videolink${i}`]
```